# Performance Optimization in Java

Tags: java, oracle, performance, collections, datatable

In Java code I am trying to fetch 3500 rows from DB(Oracle). It takes almost 15 seconds to load the data. I have approached storing the result in Cache and retrieving from it too. I am using simple Select statement and displaying 8 columns from a single table (No joins used) .Using List to save the data from DB and using it as source for Datatable. I have also thought from hardware side such as RAM capacity, Storage, Network speed etc... It exceeds the minimum requirements comfortably. Can you help to do it quicker (Shouldn't take more than 3 seconds)?

Comment: Please post the query; there are plenty of folks here who could offer suggestions for speeding it up.

Comment: If 3.5k rows takes 15 seconds, it is most likely a poorly-planned/plannable query. But without a lot more details .. (a query might not be SARGABLE independent of joins; eg. there might be no suitable index to cover the conditions)

Comment: The time spent is almost certainly entirely in the databse or JDBC driver. Adding 3500 record to a list in Java should take milli-seconds or less.

Comment: Post the Java code too, please.  You should be fetching in batches -- that can make a difference.

Comment: You need to first determine if this is a slow query (try running in sqlplus with auto trace on), or is slow in the java processing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented proper indexing to your tables? I don't like to ask this since this is a very basic way of optimizing your tables for queries and you mention that you have already tried several ways. One of the workarounds that works for me is that if the purpose of the query is to display the results, the code can be designed in such a way that the query should immediately display the initial data while it is still loading more data. This implies to implement a separate thread for loading and separate thread for displaying.

Comment: 15 seconds is 15 seconds (and far too long) for a 'simple query'. Using a thread can *hide* the problem, perhaps (depending on how the result is used), but it won't *fix* the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that the core problem is that you have one or more of the following:

- a poorly designed schema,
- a poorly designed query,
- an badly overloaded database, and / or
- a badly overloaded / underprovisioned network connection between the database and your client.

No amount of changing the client side (Java) code is likely to make a significant difference (i.e. a 5-fold increase) ... unless you are doing something crazy in the way you are building the list, or the bottleneck is in the display code not the retrieval.

---

You need to use some client-side and server-side performance tools to figure out whether the *real* bottleneck is the client, the server or the network. Then use those results to decide where to focus your attention.